# Symbol matrix function differentiation

Tags: symbols, debug-symbols, symbolic-math, symbolicate

1.The function 'diff' seems could only work with one-element variable 'v'

```
diff(f,v); % f(v), v is a one-lelement variable
```

while I would like do differentiation on a symbol matrix

```
diff(F, V); % F(V), V is a symbol matrix variable
```

2.If I make differentiation to each element of the symbol matrix, and obtain the result of   diff(F, V), while the result is in element by element format,

```
[g1(v_i), g2(v_i), ..., gn(v_i)]
```

so I want to know are there some methods to make the result in symbol matrix variable format like this?

```
g(V)
```

3.for example

```
diff(x^T*A*x, x) = A^T*x + A*x; % A is a constant matrix, x is a vector
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [`jacobian`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/jacobian.html).

Comment: not exactly, the result of jacobian function of matlab is expanded like the 2th above.

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood what you want to see. Is this a question on the output/display, or are you looking for how to get `g(V)` as the input for the derivative?

Comment: e.g.
If the output of the jacobian of matlab is

    ans = 
      [a11+b11, a12+b12; a21+b21, a22+b22]

However, I want to obtain the output like this

    ans = 
      A+B

Comment: Sorry, Symbolic Math Toolbox cannot do that (maybe in specific cases, but I cannot think of any). You could contact support@mathworks.com and suggest an enhancement, of course.